# Accepted graphic missing in questions tab

Tags: bug, design

[image]

---

On other sites an accepted post is highlighted *(top image).* Not the case here. '[Questions tab](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions)' view for both images above.

Comment: nice observation!

Comment: It's probably a bug at the moment. Previously, I remember seeing the accepted answers on Questions tab.

Comment: @Farhan - found a dupe, looks like it's a much older issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a perhaps somewhat nicer CSS tweak, based on the front page style:

```
.statscontainer .answered-accepted strong {
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #15B58A;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 36px;
    margin: -10px auto 0 auto;
}
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image: Screenshot]

(And yes, this is going into the next version of my [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch (SOUP)](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) user script / extension.)

Comment: free hand arrow, definitely better!

Comment: @ymb1: *Disclaimer: Screenshot is for illustrative purposes only. Actual appearance may vary. Freehand arrow may not appear on actual page.* :)

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime you can put something like this in your browser style sheet:

```
@-moz-document domain("aviation.stackexchange.com") {
    div.answered-accepted {
        background-color: palegoldenrod !important
    }
}
```

I use [Stylus](https://add0n.com/stylus.html) extension but you may enter it directly in the [browser styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867254/browsers-default-css-for-html-elements).

> [image]